# PHP PDO bindParam with html content

Tags: php, pdo

I try to save html content to the database, with ' or " it auto give a slash which is great so I don't have to do mysql_escape_string. However when I load up the string it shows as

```
<a href=/"yes/">test</a>
```

and if I save it again I got this

```
<a href=//"yes//">test</a>
```

Does that means when I echo out the string I should strip out the slash?

```
$html = '<a href="yes">test</a>';
$insertStatement = $pdo->prepare('insert into content (html) values (:html)');
$pdo->bindParam(:html, $html);
$pdo->execute();
```

Comment: Please should us the PDO code.

Comment: No. It means you should thoroughly read about magic quotes, and disable it. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: use bindValue instead of bindParam

Comment: You need to quote `:html` in the method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$pdo->bindValue(':html', $html, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

instead of

```
$pdo->bindParam(:html, $html);
```