# Using PDO to store HTML

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP PDO bindParam with html content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942972/php-pdo-bindparam-with-html-content)

I'm using PDO prepared statement to insert/update a new blog article for my web app. Everything is being entered in to the database except the article body, which contains HTML tags from a WYSIWYG editor.

Let' say `$content` contains `<p>This is a test article</p>`. It just won't insert using a prepared statement. However, it will insert the data if I don't use the prepared statement.

How can I get around this issue?

**Here is my query:**

```
$SQL = "UPDATE blog_articles SET topic_id = :topic_id, title = :title, ";
$SQL .= "title_slug = :title_slug, description = :description, ";
$SQL .= "keywords = :keywords, content = :content WHERE article_id = :article_id;";
$STH = $DBH->prepare($SQL);

// other binds ...
$STH->bindParam(':content', trim($content));
// other binds ..

$STH->execute();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942972/php-pdo-bindparam-with-html-content): Use

```
$pdo->bindValue(':html', $html, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

instead of

```
$pdo->bindParam(:html, $html);
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, that worked. Don't really get the bindParam and bindValue differences — better start reading!

Comment: NP. There's a discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue) about it, along with links to the documentation.