# Storing huge text in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I wan't to make setting for body so i will be able to edit my body from admin panel. I can do it by SQL but i wan't to ask you is it bad for server performance, That on every visit huge text from SQL will be requested

Or maybe it's better to leave body in index.php and edit with php

Actually my question is what is better for storing huge text that will be in use always SQL or TEXT(.php) file?

Comment: Possible references: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7833465/2298301 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10942972/2298301

Comment: just curious. Approximately,  how many kilobytes, megabytes etc would you consider to be 'huge'? e,g 20 KB, 120 KB, 2 MB, 10 MB... How many entries will you have?

Comment: Around 20KB, not to big but compared to other SQL content (users) it look big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that using SQL should be just fine.

However, storing data in files and reading them when page is being loaded is surely faster then retrieving it from SQL.

If you want to save even more performance, use in-memory cache like APCu for example.